# Using ajax request variable to populate a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My limits in javascript are preventing me to solve a problem I am facing at present.
I am doing an ajax request for retrieving some database values.
I receive the data I need alright, but
I am unable to use that value "cityareax" to either populate an existing dropdown or to create a new one.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autocomp_city() {
    var min_length = 2; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $("#city_namex").val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "city_ajax_refresh.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {keyword:keyword},
          success:function(data){
            $("#city_list").show();
            $("#city_list").html(data);
          }
        });
    } else {
        $("#city_list").hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item - a city name
function set_item(cityname, statename, cityarea) {
    $("#city_namex").val(cityname);
    $("#statex").val(statename);
    // hide proposition list
    $("#city_list").hide();

    $("#cityareax").val(cityarea); 
}
</script>
```

Can somebody help me?
tx Roberto

Comment: What's stopping you?  In what way does this not work?

Comment: Can you show some of your HTML and an example of the response from `city_ajax_refresh.php`?

Comment: Roberto, you have everything set up, you could either pass the data received as an array (and loop it in the function) or you can put a for loop, looping through the data in `success:function(data){...}`.

Comment: Where is the function call of each?

Comment: can you post here what is output of your data variable on success function?

Comment: I am receivcing data allright, I just don't know how to make the dropdown and use that data I receive. The other two values "city_namex and statex" go fine into an INPUT field using their ID. With the "cityareax" I haven't found a way of populating a dropdown. I can program good in php, but I am very weak in JS, I have to say ...

Comment: @Matt I have tried something similar, but my poor knowledge of JS is leading to no results. If you could just make a complete function for me, I would be able to tweak it to work. TX

Comment: @ DOCTYPE HTML. Function is an Ajax call I got in the web that is returning the variables I need, that is not the issue. Problem is I am not able to make use of that variable I receive because of my poor JS knowledge. TX

Comment: @Siddharth Vaghasia It's kind of complex. I am doing, though this, an autocomplete on two input fields using database search data. And it is working ok. "city_namex" & "statex" are two strings that go in Input fields, fine so far. "cityareax" is a string I receive that I am not able to use to populate a dropdown. But I receive the string allright. TX

Comment: @ Hydrothermal html here

    <div class="city_input_container">
    <input type="text" class='inputline1' id="city_namex" name="city_namex" autocomplete='off' style = "margin-bottom:0px;" onkeyup="autocomp_city()">
    <input type="text" class='inputline1' id="statex" name="statex">
    
    <ul id="city_list"></ul>
    </div>

resultes:
Riachão das Neves
Bahia
whatever I format in php

I don't think the "special chars" are an issue, they seem to believe ok. TX

Answer (score 1):

and thanks for your interest. I found my own solution. The main problem was timing.

I was trying to use data that I received from Ajax in a script that was inactive, having been executed onload.

When I moved my variable processing code in the function that was working AFTER THE AJAX REQUEST, everything went fine. It was about a week that I was running in circles trying to find a solution ...

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a return type?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "city_ajax_refresh.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {keyword:keyword},
  datatype: "html",
  success:function(data){
    $("#city_list").show();
    $("#city_list").html(data);
  }
});
```

What's the php output?

Need to use echo in PHP instead of return.

```
<?php 
  $output = some_function();
  echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Travis, PHP output is 3 strings. Names, made of two or more words & with accents. But I receive them fine, and 2 of them go into Input fields as they should. I receive the third one fine too but I wasn't able to make a dropdown out of it. My knowledge of JS is very basic. I tried to associate the cityareax value using an ID, triyng to put it into. a <select> or <option> or a <div> No way. It goes well into an INPUT using the id="cityareax". I have used echo in php:     echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.$cityname_fix.'\', \''.$rs['statename'].'\', \''.$cityarea.'\')">'.$drop_cityname.'</li>';